# Unable to remove all apostrophe in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to replace apostrophe from my string with double apostrophe, i used `preg_match and str_ireplace` but i can't remove all of them.

```
$track= preg_replace('/([\'\x{0027}]|&#39;)/u', "''", $track);
```

or

```
$track= str_ireplace("'", "''", $track);
```

after running this only few of the apostrophe are replaced and others remain
[image]

Comment: Open a hex editor and check it's value. If it isn't `27`, then there's your problem.

Comment: Removal and replacing with a double apostrophe are two different things. Are you perhaps looking for a proper database escaping function?

Comment: Paste your test input string here.

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt my string is from the database and i want to write it to a sql file

Comment: @mario no i want to write it to a file like `(12, 'Armin Van Buuren''s', ' ASOT 650')` not `(12, 'Armin Van Buuren's', ' ASOT 650')` as it gives me an error.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using escaping functions specific for MySQL syntax instead of trying to roll your own?